# Random junk when copying array

Tags: c++, arrays, null, copying

When I run this program it runs fine but for some reason I'm getting random junk in the output. If I enter a string greater than 11 characters I will start to get random junk, if I enter less than 11 characters the random junk doesn't appear and it looks fine...

Here is a picture of the error [image]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main ()
{
    //Declare and initialize variables
    char str1 [100], str2 [100] ;
    int i, y ;

    //Top display
    cout << endl
    << "Copy one string to a second string\n"
    << "----------------------------------\n" ;

    //Read user input
    cout << "Please enter a string: " ;
    cin.getline (str1 , sizeof (str1) ) ;
    cout << endl ;

    //Make copy using strcpy
    for ( i = 0 ; str1[i] != '\0'; i ++ )
    {
        str2[i] = str1[i] ;
        cout << i << "  " ;
    }


    y = sizeof (str2) ;

    //Display results
    cout << endl
    << "Str1: " << str1 << " has been copied into str2: " << str2 << endl
    << "y: " << y << endl ;


    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: [Seems to work](https://rextester.com/REGZN97907) for me. What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik [link](https://i.imgur.com/tH9F1Dr.png)
Here is a pic of the error. When I enter 12 characters or above it gives random junk. But at 11 characters and under there is no junk.

Comment: Thou shalt null-terminate c-style strings. `str1[i] != '\0'` stops the copying before `str2` gets the terminator.

Comment: @user4581301 that makes sense! How do I copy the null terminator character to str2? `str2[i] = str1[i]` ?

Comment: Path of least resistance would be to add `str2[i] = '\0';` after the loop

Comment: Note though: the comment `//Make copy using strcpy` suggests that you should be using the `strcpy` function. No loop just call `strcpy(str2, str1);` [Documentation page for `strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)

Comment: @user4581301 yes that was by mistake. I deleted the strcpy functions. But I was able to figure it out, thanks!

Comment: just a side note: you know the difference between sizeof and strlen here, right?

Comment: @user4581301 sizeof returns the number of elements an array is allotted and strlen returns the character length of the string I believe. I just added those random calcs in there to help me figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: You do not mean `y = sizeof (str2)`. Surely you mean `y = strlen(str2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It works.. try add below between the end of `for` block and `y=sizeof` to aid debugging

```
str2[i] = 0;
cout<<"\nstr2 is "<<i<<" characters:  ==" << str2 <<"==" << " \n" ;
```

and clearer is simply `getline (cin,str1);`

Comment: `getline (cin,str1);` is not clearer, it would not compile here. That would work if `str1` is a `std::string`, not char array

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with a lot less code by just declaring two strings. Then set string 2 to string 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string str1;
string str2;

int main() {
    cout << "String 1 is now :\t" << str1 << endl;
    cout << "String 2 is now :\t" << str2 << endl;
    cout << "Enter a String" << endl;
    getline(cin, str1);
    str2 = str1;
    cout << "String 1 has been copied into string 2" << endl;
    cout << "String 1 is now :\t" << str1 << endl;
    cout << "String 2 is now :\t" << str2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not null terminate the new string. Something like this after your loop will do the trick:

```
// null terminate the string
if(i < 100) {
    str2[i] = 0;
} else {
    // terminate the last character anyway
    str2[99] = 0;
}
```

This has hardcoded values. I would probably change that.

This isn't necessarily the best way to null terminate your string. But at least you know what's going on now.

---

Also, `sizeof` is a compile time constant denoting the size of the array. I'm going to guess that this is not what you want, but rather you want `strlen()` instead. `strlen()` gives the length of the string instead.

```
y = strlen(str2);
```

But I suppose that is speculation on my part.